# How to make the menu open by default?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, menu, dropdown

On my website "Bootstrap", I created a navigation menu.

The menu includes a sub menu. How to make the menu open by default ?

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
  <li class="dropdown open">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle fa-lg"></i> Besoin d'aide ?</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="/guide" data-drupal-link-system-path="/guide"><i class="fas fa-paw fa-lg"></i> Suivez le guide</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/demande" data-drupal-link-system-path="/demande"><i class="fas fa-ticket-alt fa-lg"></i> Consultez les demandes</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/question" data-drupal-link-system-path="/question"><i class="fas fa-question fa-lg"></i> Foire aux question</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I tried with JS but it does not work, the class is not added :

```
  if ($("#navbar-collapse-first .views-manage-menu").length) {
      $("#navbar-collapse-first .views-manage-menu .dropdown").addClass("open");
  };
```

If I change the name of the class, it is added and it works :

```
  if ($("#navbar-collapse-first .views-manage-menu").length) {
      $("#navbar-collapse-first .views-manage-menu .dropdown").addClass("xopen");
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

**solution with js:**

give your ul an id (id="navigation"),
in the <head> write `<script>location.hash = 'navigation';</script>`

the difference between location.hash and location.href is, that hash don't reload the site.

in your stylesheet add:

```
#navigation {
  /*...*/
  display: none;
}
#navigation:target {
  display: block;
  /*or whatever you want to display*/
}
```

I dont know an automatic solution without js, so if you dont want to use it, you have to open it automatically. You could place the non-js code in a <noscript>.

```css
a#openNavigation {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a#openNavigation:active~ul#navigation,
ul#navigation:hover {
  display: block;
}

ul#navigation {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  display: none;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<a id="openNavigation">open</a>
<ul id="navigation" class="menu menu--main nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="expanded dropdown active open">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle fa-lg"></i> Besoin d'aide ?</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
      <li>
        <a href="/guide" data-drupal-link-system-path="/guide"><i class="fas fa-paw fa-lg"></i> Suivez le guide</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/demande" data-drupal-link-system-path="/demande"><i class="fas fa-ticket-alt fa-lg"></i> Consultez les demandes</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/question" data-drupal-link-system-path="/question"><i class="fas fa-question fa-lg"></i> Foire aux question</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

make sure that the button in the last example is exactly below the ul, if not the ul disapper after you click on the link.

Comment: Thank you but that's not what I'm looking for. In my example, there is the class "open". But when I load my page, the class is not applied.

Comment: another solution if you using a local server: change the ip adress (localhost, 127.0.0.1, for me: 192.168.1.4) or use the incognito mode (firefox: private browsing)

Comment: ok that sounds like a cache problem... im using chrome for web development but in firefox it should be similar. open your development window (F12 or so) go to Sources (the tabs on the top) and then select in the folder-like menu the javascript where your class schould modified. open it, scroll to the correct line and look if it is there. if not, select open in new tab (right click) and reload the js until its loaded. then reload your site. If it doesnt work: look in the source code (view-source:localhost/...) if the class is mentioned in the ul. if not add it in the development window.